# Ambiguity with the case of relative pronoun followed directly by a name (noun)

Tags: parallelism, relative-pronouns

Here I have a practice GMAT exercise, the answer to which I am having a hard time grasping it. The exercise is as follows and the goal is to pick a replacement from five choices for the part in bold.

> In 1713, Alexander Pope began **his translation of the Iliad, a work that, taking him seven years until completion, and that literary critic Samuel Johnson, Pope's contemporary, pronounced** the greatest translation in any language.

Final answer:

> In 1713, Alexander Pope began **his translation of the Iliad, a work that took him seven years to complete and that literary critic Samuel Johnson, Pope's contemporary, pronounced** the greatest translation in any language.

I am having trouble comprehending this answer, in particular the part **"that literary critic ..."**. The **"that"** is a relative pronoun referring to the translation work. I find it somewhat odd to see/read a relative pronoun directly followed by a name (noun). It seems like I could read it as if it's referring to a particular Samuel Johnson out of many.

Not sure what I am missing here. Perhaps, a couple examples (simpler) with the same pattern would help with my understanding. Thanks.

Comment: Is your first blockquote correct? It's not a complete sentence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth
The first blockquote is what's given to you in the exercise along with five choices, from which you are asked to pick one that you think is the most suitable to replace the part in bold. One of choices is keeping the original version and thus determining the correctness of the given version is also part of the exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing anything. There are two parses -- which is probably what troubles you -- and context gives the proper choice, namely the one in which the second *that* is a relative pronoun in parallel with the first *that*, giving the meaning

> a work **that** took him seven years to complete, [a work ...] **that** literary critic Samuel Johnson, Pope's contemporary, pronounced....

The alternate parse requires taking the second *that* as a demonstrative, with the meaning

> ... and **that** literary critic Samuel Johnson [in contrast to *this* literary critic of the same name], Pope's contemporary, pronounced....

Taking this parse flies in the fact of the fact that there aren't two identically-named literary critics who opined on Pope's translation. But that's a semantic consideration, not a syntactic one.

Comment: Thanks @deadrat. That really helps. Here is a follow-up for you. Let's ignore the context for now and focus on only the sentence structure. Would it be wrong when those two **that's** are not in parallel? If not, I would really appreciate to see another example with similar structure.

Comment: @tamakisquare Context is everything. I think you're asking if the second parse might make sense. Sure: *I sent my agent a novel that took me seven years to write, and that bastard never ever bothered to reply.*

Comment: Good example there. I think I got it. Thanks for your time. Much appreciated.

Comment: @tamakisquare The French (wisely? serendipitously?) have different words for the relative pronoun and the determiner.

Comment: There _is_ a syntactic requirement if the choice is between 'and that literary critic Samuel Johnson, Pope's contemporary, pronounced the greatest translation in any language.' and 'and that literary critic Samuel Johnson, Pope's contemporary, pronounced it the greatest translation in any language.' A 'dub' verb needs two noun phrases.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Thanks for sharing your thoughts. Very interesting :)